# How to remove some value from SQL Table by query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to remove some value from all rows for example I have a table `CustomerImage`. And I have below data in that table.

```
+---------+--------------------------------+
| Serial  | Link                           |
+---------+--------------------------------+
| 001     | pages/small/image001.jpg       |
| 002     | pages/small/image002.jpg       |
| 003     | pages/small/image003.jpg       |
| 004     | pages/small/image004.jpg       |
| 005     | pages/small/image005.jpg       |
| 006     | pages/small/image006.jpg       |
| 007     | pages/small/image007.jpg       |
| 008     | pages/small/image008.jpg       |
| 009     | pages/small/image009.jpg       |
| 010     | pages/small/image010.jpg       |
+---------+--------------------------------+
```

In above table I want to remove pages/small/ from all rows. Above table just for example I have a large database.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @MikeCheel what you mean by that ?

Comment: I mean where is the sql you would like help with?

Comment: He means we don't write code for you. We help you improve the code you write.

Comment: @MikeCheel & @Nick Zimmerman 

Here is my code
`
declare @table table
  (
 url nvarchar(200)
  )
  declare @Link  nvarchar(100)
  declare c cursor for select Link FROM CustomerImage
  OPEN c
  fetch next from c into @Link
  WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
  begin
  
set @Link= REPLACE(@Link,'pages/small/','')
INSERT into @table(Link) VALUES(@Link)

   fetch next from c into @Link
   
  end
  SELECT * from @table
  CLOSE c
  DEALLOCATE c
`

Comment: @skgacharya - edit your original question and add the code there, not in a comment.  Also, refrain from using cursors if at all possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably want to wrap this all in a transaction and SELECT the results to make sure you get it right.

```
BEGIN TRAN
UPDATE CustomerImage SET Link = REPLACE(Link, 'pages/small/', '')
SELECT * FROM CustomerImage
ROLLBACK  --change this to a commit after you're sure it's working the way you want
```

Comment: how to add some value in starting of the rows

Comment: @skgacharya - I don't understand what you're asking.  Do you need to change the `Link` column to something else?  Update another field?  Are you asking two separate questions?

Comment: Yes I'm asking second question. I have replace the value from all rows  that's fine now i want to add ..product/ in the starting of every row.

Comment: Every row's `Link` field?  Why didn't you just replace "pages/small/" with "product/"?  Perhaps you should attempt to understand how `REPLACE` works.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx